# How to get parent directory url using yii

Tags: url, yii

I have a admin folder under main project folder. My project is being created in core php and admin with YII.

How can i get the main url without admin parameter using yii.

**Current URl :** http://localhost/project/admin

**Needed URL :** http://localhost/project

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Yii 1.1.16 I get base URL with:

```
Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)
```

Comment: @Vik Verma Why don't you try to go into your Yii backend config file and do this: `'basePath'=>dirname(__DIR__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',` This way PHP will if I'm reading the docs correctly get the parent directory of currrent directory which is what you need, right? Then when you call Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) it will return localhost/project

Answer (score 0):

You have installed yii for admin section, so base url will return the path till admin directory. Use hostinfo property of Yii Request Class.

```
Yii::app()->request->hostInfo
```

For more detail you can check here.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#baseUrl-detail

Comment: Hey anamika, I've tried this but it returns only **http://localhost**. However i need it including project. that is **http://localhost/projects/**

Comment: You can set the front path from the base url. 

`$baseurl=Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);
 $basearray=explode('/admin',$baseurl);
 Yii::setPathOfAlias('fronturl',$basearray[0]);
 echo Yii::getPathOfAlias('fronturl');`